# Set iPython to run latest Python version

Tags: python, macos

I just downloaded Python 3.9.2 from Python's web site and installed it on my MacBook.  Running `python3` from the terminal loads it up.  However, when I run `ipython`, the Python version it uses is 3.8.6.  I know that `ipython` is itself a Python script but I don't trust myself to fiddle with it properly.

How can I make iPython use the latest version of Python?

Comment: How did you install `ipython` for python3.8?

Comment: I installed it in the terminal with brew.

Comment: Not familiar with brew. I used pip in a virtual environment (created by python3.9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling iPython via brew and reinstalling it with pip3 ended up doing the trick (after restarting the terminal).